# Having trouble with OnItemTouchListener and Updation of RecyclerView in Android

Tags: android, onclick, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

This is my MainActivity RecyclerView addOnItemTouchListener Implementation.

```
recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerViewTouchListener(this, recyclerView, new NewAlbumAdapter.RecyclerViewClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, int position) {
                String[] allImagePathListInAnAlbum;
                Log.e("Item Clicked is","++++ "+allAlbumsName[position]);
                Log.e("Item Number is", "++++ " +String.valueOf(position));
                allImagePathListInAnAlbum=filePathToAllAlbums[position].list();
                Intent insideAlbumIntent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ImagesInsideAlbumMainActivity.class);
                insideAlbumIntent.putExtra("AllImagePath",allImagePathListInAnAlbum);
                startActivity(insideAlbumIntent);

            }

            @Override
            public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),allAlbumsName[position]+" Is Long clicked\nAt Position: "+String.valueOf(position),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }
        }));
```

This is the RecyclerViewTouchListener I have implemented.

```
public class RecyclerViewTouchListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener{

    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
    private NewAlbumAdapter.RecyclerViewClickListener clickListener;

    public RecyclerViewTouchListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, final NewAlbumAdapter.RecyclerViewClickListener clickListener) {
        this.clickListener = clickListener;
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
                View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
                if (child != null && clickListener != null) {
                    clickListener.onLongClick(child, recyclerView.getChildPosition(child));
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

        View child = rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
        if (child != null && clickListener != null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
            clickListener.onClick(child, rv.getChildPosition(child));
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {    }

}
```

When I click the item which were previously added in the RecyclerView the clicks works fine. Only 1 time onClick is called.

But when I add an item into the RecyclerView and click on the newly created item, the onClick method is called twice.

```
@Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

        View child = rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
        if (child != null && clickListener != null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
            clickListener.onClick(child, rv.getChildPosition(child));
        }
        return false;
    }
```

False is returned from it. And it goes to this method in RecyclerView:
I ran the debugger and I have commented the values of a few things:

```
if (action != MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) //action:1
 {

final int listenerCount = mOnItemTouchListeners.size(); //listenerCount=2
//While for previously added items it was 1 only.

for (int i = 0; i < listenerCount; i++) {

final OnItemTouchListener listener = mOnItemTouchListeners.get(i);

if (listener.onInterceptTouchEvent(this, e)) {//e:MotionEvent {action==ACTION_UP
                   mActiveOnItemTouchListener = listener;
                   return true;
                }
```

However if clicked on item which were previously added then it works perfectly fine.

I want only one time the OnClick shoud be called. But it is being called 2 times.

I am adding file folders to a directory and trying to update the contents of the recyclerView by :

```
    public void onFinishEditDialog(String inputText) {
            newAlbumName = inputText;
            initAllVariables();
initRecyclerViewForAlbumView();
        }
```

It re-initializes all the variables and

```
public void initRecyclerViewForAlbumView() {
        RecyclerView recyclerView;


        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

        GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(MainActivity.this, 2);

        //recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new GridSpacingItemDecoration(spanCount,spacing,includeEdge));
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);

        newAlbumAdapter = new NewAlbumAdapter(recyclerView.getContext(),filePathToAllAlbums,allAlbumsName,countOfAlbums,firstImageOfAllFile);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(newAlbumAdapter);

        recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerViewTouchListener(this, recyclerView, new RecyclerViewClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, int position) {
                String[] allImagePathListInAnAlbum;
                Log.e("Item Clicked is", "++++ " + allAlbumsName[position]);
                Log.e("Item Number is", "++++ " + String.valueOf(position));
                allImagePathListInAnAlbum = filePathToAllAlbums[position].list();
                Intent insideAlbumIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ImagesInsideAlbumMainActivity.class);
                insideAlbumIntent.putExtra("AllImagePath", allImagePathListInAnAlbum);
                startActivity(insideAlbumIntent);

            }

            @Override
            public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), allAlbumsName[position] + " Is Long clicked\nAt Position: " + String.valueOf(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }
        }));

    }
```

I have 2 questions:

1> Is there any other way to update the RecyclerView and to show the newly added directory on the Activity. (I have used all notify methods but they don't seem to work).

2> The onClick in the `OnTouchItemListener` is called twice if I re-initialize RecyclerView in `onFinishEditDialog`. If I don't do it the OnClick is working fine but the newly created directory will not be shown on the Activity.

Please help to resolve this issue.
I will be very thankful if anyone could help.